# CosmosDb Entity Framework Core provider logging

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to get logging for the CosmosDb Entity Framework Core provider to see the queries that are being executed. I also want to measure the Request Units for performance reasons to the local emulator. Not using EF Core there is a response from the CosmosDbClient, but in this specific case I want it using 
the EF Core CosmosDb provider.

Looking at https://dotnetfalcon.com/entity-framework-core-cosmos-db-provider/ it seems possible, but logging that way is deprecated and doesn't even compile on .NET Core 3.1

Also looking at the source, the IDiagnisticsLogger for DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command is implemented
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/9abd61d3fb4cdd1041f25fe2e10c70ee3dc4055e/src/EFCore.Cosmos/Diagnostics/Internal/CosmosLoggerExtensions.cs

I tried the following in Startup.cs, but sadly there is no query printed in the console.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    _applicationOptions = GetApplicationOptions(services);

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseCosmos(_applicationOptions.AccountEndpoint, _applicationOptions.AccountKey, "MySecretDb");
        options.UseLoggerFactory(GetLoggerFactory());
    });

    ...
}

private ILoggerFactory GetLoggerFactory()
{
    IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
            builder.AddConsole()
                .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug));
    }
    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
}
```

**Code configuration works**

Use the host logging configuration it works without the code above, but I do rather configure it in Startup.cs or else in appsettings.{env}.json

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Debug);
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
```

**Logging section in config doesn't work**

I have tried this in my development json, which should work but somehow doesn't work

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "IncludedScopes": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Debug"
      },
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
```

How to get it working using CreateDefaultBinder which takes the appsettings.{env}.json ?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Debug"` for in the LogLevel section of your configuration.
But even more specific filter you use should work. Here is what I tried:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Debug"
    }
  }
```

One important point: I don't specify custom logger factory, the default one is  injected atomatically. For the configuration to be loaded from the config system (incl. json file) in case of manual creation of logger factory you need to have this:

```
loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
```

This is exactly what `CreateDefaultBuilder` does for the default logging factory.

Comment: You are one year too late with answering ;) I do not know if your answer is correct and I'm long past the question myself. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry man,  maybe it'll be useful to somebody else :)